# SED is giving me issues

Tags: bash, sed

I am working on a really basic script:

1) Grabs account keys from a text file (keyList.txt) --> key format looks like this: 1002000222,1002000400

2) For each key I am looping through and inserting them (using SED) into SQL queries held in another text file.

3) Query example:

```
UPSERT INTO ACCT_HIST (ACCT_KEY) SELECT ACCT_KEY FROM ACCT_HIST WHERE ACCT_KEY IN (101000033333) AND REC_ACTV_IND = 'Y' AND DT_KEY < 20191009;
```

My Bash snippet is below but to summarize the issue, SED is only replacing the values in the parenthesis one key at a time, rather than placing them both in the same parenthesis space. The below is now working perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H:%M")

cp acct_transfer_soft_del_list.csv keyList_$now.txt

for key in $(<keyList_$now.txt)
do
        sed "s/([^)]*)/(${key})/3" hbase.txt >> queries_$now.txt
done
```

hbase.txt holds the queries but I don't want to permanently change them, so I send the output to queries_$now.txt.

Comment: I think you are writing an output file for the first key, and then replacing that output with another one for the second key. Is your goal to have two output files?  Or one output file with a copy of each query for each key?

Comment: Don't set `IFS` globally (`IFS=, read f1 f2`), and don't use a for loop to iterate over the file; see [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, note that you have `IFS=,`.

This is (probably) breaking your key with a unwanted behaviour.

I admit that I am not sure I understood entirely what you need, but I think you can use the first cycle in order to get everything you need.

Reusing your code, you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H:%M")

IFS=","
while read f1 f2
do
  echo "$f1,$f2"
  sed "s/([^\)]*)/($f1,$f2)/3 " hbase.txt >> queries_$now.txt
done < acct_transfer_soft_del_list.csv > keyList_$now.txt
```

Anyway, I can't get straight your while cycle: it seems to do a simple copy of your file.
You could avoid it with `cp acct_transfer_soft_del_list.csv keyList_$now.txt`

Comment: If you have three fields, the var `f2` will be `field2,field3`. You can try it with `printf "field1,field2,field3\n" | while IFS=, read -r f1 f2; do echo "${f1} ${f2}"; done`; if you don't need to edit the separator, you can actually use a single var, like `while read line; do \sed part\; done <file`